# Getting UI input during background work on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, inter-process-communicat

I'm currently working on a simple elevator Android game. The user can add passengers on several floors, where they wait until the elevator picks them up. If so, the passenger has to choose a destination floor within the elevator.
For each game cycle the elevator loads / unloads passengers, chooses its direction and moves.

The problem now is that during one iteration, the user has to choose the destination floor for each loaded passenger. Therefore I would need to somehow run the elevator cycle in the background, but within one iteration get several UI inputs, whereas the background thread would have to wait for all inputs to be completed.

Does anyone know a (good) solution for that?

Thanks in advance

EDIT for better understanding a simplified view on the code

```
public class Elevator {
    public void iterate() {
       unloadPassengers();
       loadPassengers();
       move(); 
    }

    private void loadPassengers() {

    //if elevator isn't idle collect passengers going in same direction
    if (!operation.isIdle()) {
        Collection<Passenger> passengers = currentFloor.loadPassengers(operation.getDirection());

        if (!passengers.isEmpty()) {

            for (Passenger passenger : passengers) {

                //!! chooseDestinationFloor() is the method where the user has to choose his destination floor, which requires UI input for each passenger during the background lifecycle; Here I would need this thread to block for each passenger until I got user input
                passenger.setDestinationFloor(passenger.chooseDestinationFloor());
                loadedPassengers.put(passenger.getDirection(), passenger);
            }
            firePassengersLoaded(currentFloor, passengers.toArray(new Passenger[passengers.size()]));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: post code where you do action in background thread

Answer (score 0):

try to use `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                //your code to show user input here
            }
        });`

Comment: My problem is that I have to wait for the UI result on the background thread. runOnUiThread() only adds code asynchronously to the ui thread, without any callback